# HTML Audio Player that supports wav file with bit rate of 13Kbps

Tags: html, audio, wav, jplayer

Tried using Jpalyer It didnt work. Requirement is to play wav files with bit rate 13. From what i have read browsers only support 8 and 16 Kbps files. But the files i need to be played are in 13Kbps.